# Can't get prefers-color-scheme html media attribute to work

Tags: html

According to this [blog post](https://jross.me/updating-your-website-favicon-dynamically-with-dark-mode/) you cant change the favicon for dark mode with the following code.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon-nopref.ico" media="(prefers-color-scheme:no-preference)">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon-dark.ico" media="(prefers-color-scheme:dark)">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" media="(prefers-color-scheme:light)">
```

However, I am merely getting the favicon of the link that was defined last (i.e. for the above code favicon.ico).

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work starting in Chrome 91. See https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/OwUSsHWokpA and the working example below:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="default.ico" />

<link rel="icon" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" href="dark.ico" />

<link rel="icon" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" href="light.ico" />
```

You can play with it at https://media-link.glitch.me/

Comment: To add to François' answer, if you need support for earlier browser versions, you can also try to use an SVG icon with embedded styles and `prefers-color-scheme`. See my [blog post](https://blog.tomayac.com/2019/09/21/prefers-color-scheme-in-svg-favicons-for-dark-mode-icons/) for details and a working example.